# Classification of Categories in Text Data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

This may be an abstract question, but I always face difficulties with this kind of problem and it keeps on coming to me.

I crawled data (example: news articles about Tata Steel) extracted the content, manually read the content of each link and classified them as Finance, Operation, Sustainability and so on.

Then I made tf-idf data frame to be the features for classifier model.

I want to train the model to classify these articles. I am only left with either SVM or Logistic using the tf-idf features.

Is there a better approach to clssify text data? Can there be better approach rather then making tf-idf as we may loose information (contextual meaning of sentence) when breaking them into words and use as features.

Any algorithm which can help me to improve classification on text data?

Comment: How will the contextual meaning helpful in your case ? If you are worried about the sentence formation - try Doc2Vec risking the context value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several commercial APIs as well as frameworks for text classification task that improve upon SVM/logistic on tf-idf. They include the semantic/context/word order in sentences for classification. Deep Neural Nets have been quite useful in this task and you can research LSTM and RNN test classification if you want to build a neural net from scratch. For existing and easier to get started, you can look at Spacy and FastText. Both have examples of labeling and training data for classification models

Comment: I'll not suggest Neural Net unless you have at least 100k documents for training.

Comment: @UDay Good point - a large training set is required but I don't agree that it needs to be 100K could even be less than a hundred. Depends on how well separated the classes are. In the OP case - there should be good separation between the main words about: Finance, Operation, Sustainability and so on

Comment: I have 500 articles with skewed distribution. Like 4 categories having distribution as (280,120,60,40) so at time of classifying it's not taking the skewed classes. How can we solve this problem.? All are classified  into first two classes.

Comment: @DreamerP Which framework / tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 (Spyder) and currently trying out with SVM algo.

Answer (score 1):

If you clean your features well enough, no reason a simple naive bayes can't perform well. Focus on removing any words you already know to be low information-gain, and then trim features again after fitting your model.

A labeled LDA, or L-LDA is another option.

Comment: I have 500 articles with skewed distribution. Like 4 categories having distribution as (280,120,60,40) so at time of classifying it's not taking the skewed classes. How can we solve this problem.? All are classified into first two classes.

Comment: One question per post. You've gotten several good answers. Mark one correct, try to implement them and, if unsuccessful, post another, specific question.

Comment: John H, I do not have enough points to mark one, :) Hope you understand.

Comment: Why my question is put on hold?

Comment: Because it’s too broad.